# MVC 3 Index Page with multiple objects

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an HomeController and in Index action i want work with multiple objects, for example i'll show News, Pictures, Portfolio in HomePage. So how can i pass multiple Objects to View.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
            var news = newsRepository.GetAll();
            return View(news);
}
```

Above, i can pass only News object to view. But as you know in HomePage of a website there will be more than only one object.

On the view when i only work with News, i can pass "IEnumerable" from a controller. But to declare more than one object in the view, what should i do? Sorry i'm a beginner in MVC3. In WebForms it was easy with user controls or .NET controls but in MVC it looks complicated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I do to solve this is use a view model with properties that contain the objects you want to pass in to the view.

I create a ViewModel folder for these classes.

```
public class IndexViewModel
{
    public PortfolioViewModel Portfolio {get; set;}
    public IEnumerable<PhotosViewModel> Photos {get; set;}
    public IEnumerable<NewsViewModel> News {get; set;}
    //...///
}
```

In your controller.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new IndexViewModel();
    model.news = newsRepository.GetAll();
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: and for the view should i pass it like "IEnumerable<IndexViewModel>" or only the IndexViewModel?

Comment: Just the object itself.  It would look like this @model IndexViewModel

Answer (score 2):

Create a model with all the subclasses- models, and send it to the view.

```
public class A
{
    public int Code {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}

public class B
{
    public int First {get; set;}
    public int Second {get; set;}
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public A TheA {get; set;}
    public B TheB {get; set;}
}

public ActionResult Index()
{
        var model = new ViewModel();
        return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can effectively create something akin to a user control by using a [ChildAction](https://www.google.com/search?q=mvc%20child%20action).

Your views / models / controllers for news, pictures, portfolio, would remain separate.

You can then combine them in the home page like so:

```
@Html.Action("Index", "News")
@Html.Action("Index", "Pictures")
@Html.Action("Index", "Portfolio")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ViewData to store multiple objects. But a better option would be to create a class that stores all those other objects that need to be passed to the view.